# Uncertainty of the fitting parameters and the function using Monte Carlo methods

Tags: regression, monte-carlo, nonlinear-regression, uncertainty

We have a set of measurements with known uncertainty both in dependent and independent variables. The uncertainties follow Gaussian distributions. The model function is known and nonlinear.

How can we obtain the uncertainty of the fitting parameters and the function using Monte Carlo methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the absence of more detail about your problem, I would suggest simulating a large number of datasets (say 1000) by drawing each point from its distribution in both dependent and independent dimensions. You can then fit your model to each of these datasets. The variation in the model parameters over the 1000 datasets should allow you to accurately quantify the uncertainty in model parameters and their covariance.